# Create single flatbuffer for multiple json files or concatenate the multiple flatbuffers created from the jsons

Tags: json, serialization, deserialization, flatbuffers

I am trying to create a single *flatbuffer* from my multiple `json` files, using the `flatc` compiler, we can create a single flatbuffer from a json file, as given in the example [Json with flatbuffers](https://google.github.io/flatbuffers/flatbuffers_guide_tutorial.html).

```
#json file example.
{
  pos: {
    x: 1,
    y: 2,
    z: 3
  },
  hp: 300,
  name: "Orc"
}

#from the command line
$./../flatc -b monster.fbs monsterdata.json
```

I've looked at the [documentation](https://google.github.io/flatbuffers/) given by google on flatbuffers and cannot figure out how to make a single **flatbuffer**. I also checked out the following google-groups [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/flatbuffers/Y9w2JhwrXG8) but couldn't comprehend much, and also to this [github link](https://github.com/cogumbreiro/fbs_tk)

Would be great if someone can help me create a single *flatbuffer* from my multiple json files, also are flatbuffers meant to be created for single `json` objects or *singular data*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that automatically. You'll need to specify exactly how you want those multiple buffers are supposed to be represented in the schema, e.g.

```
table Monsters { monsters:[Monster]; }
root_type Monsters;
```

Where `Monster` is the type of just one of your JSON files. Then you concatenate all JSON files, with `{ monsters: [` prefixed, `] }` postfixed, and `,` in between.

Comment: Also, this [link](http://frogermcs.github.io/flatbuffers-in-android-introdution/) helps alot with respect to the **schema** and also how to run `flatbuffers` on android

Comment: I have a **struct** with 512 float values, but when I make a **schema** as above, I get all my float values in a disorderly manner. Any way I can get my **struct 512** array in an  order of `a0 a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 a6 a7 ... a511` ?

Comment: what is the schema, and what is the input file?

Comment: Hi @Aardappel : You can find the **schema** and a **sample json** at this [gist](https://gist.github.com/sirius0503/620612383734e09222e7f842926738fe), also I am having this problem too, [flatc --java generated file exceeds 255 params in constructor](https://github.com/google/flatbuffers/issues/4486#issuecomment-593072813)

Comment: replace `Embedding: Vec512` by `Embedding: [float]` and delete that crazy struct :)